# how to sample from an upside down bell curve

Tags: r, statistics

I can generate numbers with uniform distribution by using the code below:

```
runif(1,min=10,max=20)
```

How can I sample randomly generated numbers that fall more frequently closer to the minimum and maxium boundaries? (Aka an "upside down bell curve")

Comment: nornal distribution does not have minimal and/or maximal values

Comment: @Gregor-reinstateMonica Ha-ha-ha-ha-ha, just proposed this solution

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux feel free to take a little of my parameter explanation and I can delete the comment.

Comment: @Gregor-reinstateMonica Done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, bell curve is usually gaussian, meaning it doesn't have min and max. You could try [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and map it to desired interval. Along the lines

```
min <- 1
max <- 20
q <- min + (max-min)*rbeta(10000, 0.5, 0.5)
```

As @Gregor-reinstateMonica noted, Beta distribution is bounded on both ends, [0...1], so it could be easily mapped into any bounded interval just by scale and shift.  It has two parameters, and symmetric if those parameters are equal. Above 1 parameters make it kind of bell distribution, but below 1 parameters make it into inverse bell, what you're looking for. You could play with them, put different values instead of 0.5 and see how it is going. Parameters equal to 1 makes it uniform.

Comment: Thank you @Severin, After tweaking between 0.5 - 0.6, I achieved my practical intention.

Answer (score 1):

Sampling from a beta distribution is a good idea. Another way is to sample a number of uniform numbers and then take the minimum or maximum of them.

According to the theory of order statistics, the cumulative distribution function for the maximum is `F(x)^n` where `F` is the cdf from which the sample is taken and `n` is the number of samples, and the cdf for the minimum is `1 - (1 - F(x))^n`. For a uniform distribution, the cdf is a straight line from 0 to 1, i.e., `F(x) = x`, and therefore the cdf of the maximum is `x^n` and the cdf of the minimum is `1 - (1 - x)^n`. As `n` increases, these become more and more curved, with most of the mass close to the ends.

A web search for "order statistics" will turn up some resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about decimal places, a hacky way would be to generate a large sample of normally distributed datapoints using `rnorm()`, then count the number of times each given rounded value appears (`n`), and then substract n from the maximum value of n (`max(n)`) to get inverse counts.

You can then use the inverse count to make a new vector (that you can sample from), i.e.:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- rnorm(100000, 100, 15)

x_tib <- round(x) %>%
  tibble(x = .) %>%
  count(x) %>%
  mutate(new_n = max(n) - n)

new_x <- rep(x_tib$x, x_tib$new_n)

qplot(new_x, binwidth = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An "upside-down bell curve" compared to the normal distribution can be sampled using the following algorithm. I write it in pseudocode because I'm not familiar with R. Notice that this sampler samples in a truncated interval (here, the interval [`x0`, `x1`]) because it's not possible for an upside-down bell curve extended to infinity to integrate to 1 (which is one of the requirements for a probability density).

In the pseudocode, `RNDU01()` is a uniform(0, 1) random number.

```
x0pdf = 1-exp(-(x0*x0))
x1pdf = 1-exp(-(x1*x1))
ymax = max(x0pdf, x1pdf)
while true
  # Choose a random x-coordinate
  x=RNDU01()*(x1-x0)+x0
  # Choose a random y-coordinate
  y=RNDU01()*ymax
  # Return x if y falls within PDF
  if y < 1-exp(-(x*x)): return x
end
```